# static methods that take Enum parameters

Tags: java, enums

I find it extremely difficult to write static methods that work for `Enums`. It's a really contrived example, but suppose you want to write a method that takes an `Enum` constant and returns the next declared one. I found (after about an hour) that you can do it as follows. It works, and doesn't generate any compiler warnings.

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> E getNextDeclared(E e) {
    int ordinal = e.ordinal();
    for (Object object : EnumSet.allOf(e.getClass())) {
        if (e.getClass().cast(object).ordinal() == ordinal + 1) {
            return e.getDeclaringClass().cast(object);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Am I missing something? Can you do it without casts? Is there any way to simplify this without generating a load of warnings? Also what is the appropriate class to write in place of `Object`?

Comment: Well, e.getClass().getEnumConstants[e.ordinal() + 1] would be simpler...

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think that should be `e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()[e.ordinal() + 1];`

Comment: Great, thank you. I thought I had to be missing something. I didn't know `getEnumConstants()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> E getNextDeclared(E e) {
    int ordinal = e.ordinal();
    for (E object : EnumSet.allOf(e.getDeclaringClass())) {
        if (object.ordinal() == ordinal + 1) {
            return object;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

or, with what Louis Wasserman suggests:

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> E getNextDeclared(E e) {
    return e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()[e.ordinal() + 1];
}
```

(although that would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of an `IllegalArgumentException` if you go too high).